# Changing React state happens a re-render later, then it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-state, react-state-management

I have a functional component managing several states, amongst other things a state, which stores the index, with which I am rendering a type of table, when clicking a suitable button. OnClick that button calls a callback function, which runs a click handler. That click handler changes the index state, to the same 'index' as the array entry, in which I store an object with information for the rendering of a child component.

I would expect, that onClick the state would change before the rendering happens, so the component could render correctly. Yet it only happens a render later.

I already tried calling the useEffect-hook, to re-render, when that index state changes, but that didn't help neither.

Here is a shortened version of the code:

```
export const someComponent = () => {
  [index, setIndex] = useState(-1);
   
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setIndex(id);
  
    // This is a function, I use to render the table
    buildNewComponent(index);
  }
}
```

Further 'down' in the code, I got the function, which is rendering the table entries. There I pass the onClick prop in the child component of the table as following:

```
<SomeEntryComponent
  onClick={() => handleClick(arrayEntry.id)}
>
// some code which is not affecting my problem
</SomeEntryComponent>
```

So as told: when that onClick fires, it first renders the component when one presses it the second time, because first then the state changes.

Could anyone tell me why that happens like that and how I could fix it to work properly?

Comment: Instead of passing the index from the state, I would pass id from the argument. you call buildNewComponent inside the same function so just pass there id not index

Comment: Think about this in basic JS control flow: when between `setIndex(id);` and `buildNewComponent(index);` *on the next line* do you think `index` has been reassigned? `[index, setIndex] =` *cannot* be reached until next time the function is called, i.e. next time the component is rendered. Just *use `id`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have stated, it is a synchronicity issue, where `index` is being updated *after* `buildComponent` has been invoked.

But from a design standpoint, it would be better to assert `index` existence by its value, as opposed to flagging it in a handler. I don't know the details behind `buildComponent`, but you can turn it into a conditional render of the component.

Your component rendering becomes derived from its data, as opposed to manual creation.

```
export const someComponent = () => {
    [index, setIndex] = useState(-1);

    const handleClick = (id) => setIndex(id);

    const indexHasBeenSelected = index !== -1
    return (
        <div>
            {indexHasBeenSelected && <NewComponent index={index} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: So just for me to understand: 
Why is the index state now being updated on the first 'click'?

Comment: The mounting of `<NewComponent />` is now "gated" by the value of `index`. The equality check `index !== -1` will always fail until `index` has been updated. That means that when `<NewComponent />` is being mounted, the `index` is ensured to have been updated.

Comment: Now I got it, thank you once again. But shouldn't it be working somehow, without implementing that 'state change'-check by oneself? Isn't that the whole idea of how react states work?

Comment: @Robby It should and does. But based on your phrasing/needs, it sounds like the component should not exist until an entry has been clicked. In order to hide it _and_ keep the index updated at all times, you need this implementation

Answer (score 1):

When calling `buildNewComponent` the `index` is not yet updated. You just called setState, there is no guarantee that the value is updated immediately after that. You could use `id` here or call `buildNewComponent` within a useEffect that has `index` as its dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can have the correct behavior if you use `useEffect` and monitor `index` changes.

```
export const someComponent = () => {
  [index, setIndex] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This is a function, I use to render the table
    buildNewComponent(index);
  }, [buildNewComponent, index])
   
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setIndex(id);    
  }
}
```

The process will be:

1. When the use clicks and call `handleClick` it will dispatch `setIndex` with a new `id`
2. The `index` will change to the same `id`
3. The `useEffect` will see the change in `index` and will call `buildNewComponent`.

One important thing is to wrap `buildNewComponent` with `useCallback` to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: I don't think `buildNewComponent` should be part of the equality check in `useEffect`. It depends on the the implementation, but it either 1. Always fail the equality check or 2. Never changes

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you, as I don't know what's is inside `buildNewComponent `, I should have mention that.

Comment: How would I wrap it the right way? If I wrap it in an extra useEffect, it tells me in the other useEffect, that it can't find the buildNewComponent (of course...). Maybe it is too late for me, but I can't imagine, how I would do that..

Comment: @Robby I don't have more information to tell you exactly what to do, but one idea is to re-think about the strategy behind `buildNewComponent`. It seems that `index` could be used as component `props` and you can work with a component tree that will keep the state and pass to the next component.

Comment: @VictorBarros I'll try around with your idea, because it seems to be the more 'react way', even if Andres solution is working and is just that simple.